# @BeforeSuite not invoked when testing a single class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a `@BeforeSuite`-annotated method.

```java
public class MySuiteTest {

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void doSomethingVeryMandatory() {
        // say, boot up an embedded database
        // and create tables for JPA-annotated classes?
    }
}

public class MySingleTest {

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        // say, tests some MyBatis mappers against the embedded database?
    }
}
```

When I test the whole test,

```
$ mvn clean test
```

everything's fine. `@BeforeSuite` runs and `@Test`s run.

When I tried to test a single class

```
$ mvn -Dtest=MySingleTest clean test
```

`doSomethingVeryMandatory()` is not invoked.

Is this normal?

Comment: I'm not a TestNG expert, but are your tests really running as a suite?

Comment: @Magnilex Hmmm, I think I have not care about the concept of `suite`. There is not `...suite.xml` but just annotations.

Comment: As I said, I haven't used TestNG much recently. But to "fix" this particular problem, you could use `@BeforeClass`. The method will be executed once, before the first test in the class. If you want to run the method before a range of classes, I would think that you need to define a suit for that.

Comment: you have to first make suite in testng.xml and then define a classes or class you need to run in that. And then invoke this testng.xml using maven, in build> plugin> (maven-surefire-plugin) configuration> suiteXmlFiles > suiteXmlFile> testng.xml...so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @BeforeSuite and @Test are in different classes.  When you run a single class, testng generates a default suite.xml with only one class in it.  Hence your @BeforeSuite is not visible to testng.  You can either extend MySuiteClass in your testclass or create a suite file and run the suite file as suggested in comments.

Comment: Besides extending the test classes from a base class implementing all listeners on can specify multiple test classes separated by a comma (and even using globbing) like `-Dtest=*SuiteTest,acme.MySingleTest` (works with Surefire 2.12)

Answer (score 0):

[Babulu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616236/babulu) comment on the question works fine, just elaborating with examples for future readers:

1. Creating a suite in TestNG config XML:

```xml
<suite name="Suite Name" verbose="0">
    <test name="TestName">
        <classes>
            <class name="MySuiteTest"/>
            <class name="MySingleTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

2. Invoking this config file using maven in pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>config/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```